# Everytime I send cloud message from onesignal wordpress plugin to mobile app it opens in browser

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, onesignal

I'm using flutter and parsed wordpress website to flutter ios and android app.
I want to send notification in app whenever i publish new post in wordpress.
Notification is receiving as well but when i tap on notification it opens in Browser.
I want to open it in App.

Comment: Hi, It seems that you are new to stackoverflow. I see that your question isn't elaborated enough. People are likely to downvote questions that are not properly asked. Have you seen "How do I ask a good question?"? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think that you are looking for this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links